# Indexing a google sheet from another python file returns 'none', however the cell has data in it

Tags: python, python-2.7, gspread

I have defined two functions in leaderboard.py, insertData(xpos, ypos, data) and indexThing(row, column). Although I am able to insert data with the insert data function, I am unable to index values in server.py. I have tried indexing directly in server.py with set values and I still received 'None'. How can I go about troubleshooting this?

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import leaderboard
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/script", methods=['POST'])
def script():
    input_string = request.form['data']
    chose = input_string[:-4]
    chose = chose.replace('http://10.0.1.36:5000/static/images/Girls/', 'G')
    chose = chose.replace('http://10.0.1.36:5000/static/images/Boys/', 'B')

    print (leaderboard.indexThing(22,3)) ##THIS RETURNS NONE  

    if 'G' in chose:
        chose = int(chose[1:len(chose)])
        print chose
        total = leaderboard.indexThing(chose, 3)
        wins = leaderboard.indexThing(chose, 4)
        print wins ##THIS RETURNS NONE 
        print total ##THIS RETURNS NONE 
    elif 'B' in chose:
        chose = int(chose[1:len(chose)])
        print chose
        total = leaderboard.indexThing(chose, 12)
        wins = leaderboard.indexThing(chose, 13)
        print wins ##THIS RETURNS NONE 
        print total ##THIS RETURNS NONE 
    return "backend response"

@app.route('/')
def static_page():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/boys.html')
def static_page2():
    return render_template('boys.html')

@app.route('/girls.html')
def static_page3():
    return render_template('girls.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='10.0.1.36', port=5000, debug=True)
```

leaderboard.py

```
#coding=utf-8
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('static/client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('Rate data').sheet1

def insertData(xpos, ypos, data):
    sheet.update_cell(xpos, ypos, data)

def indexThing(row, column):
    sheet.cell(row, column).value
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the types in all the different python functioms are consistent. Same for the Google sheets.

For example, for this line I'd try;

```
sheet.cell(int(row), (int)column).value
```

Also make sure you're actually getting a return value from the sheet.cell call. Eg what is the type of just the

```
sheet.cell(int(row), (int)column)
```

Is it what youre expecting?